# Need a textbook for math course

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, applications, bifurcation

The undergrad course is called intro the applied math, and it covers: "The unit introduces some of the principal mathematical techniques such as difference equations, differential equations and partial differential equations."

We are not given a textbook and I really want to study from one, the closer it matches to the course the better. I think it's definitely based on a textbook out there.

We are about halfway through the course. Here are some course pdfs https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u3ek0rjs7jczbhj/AAC86lV0wep07b-cua3dz00Oa?dl=0. BonusQ.pdf gives a good overview of the content

Comment: You should ask your professor/teacher. They know the course better than we do.

Comment: I did, to no avail

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly how well it fits your course, but a really great book in general is
[Nonlinear Dynamics And Chaos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738204536) by Steven Strogatz. (I wholeheartedly agree with all the rave reviews on Amazon. Besides, [Spider-Man uses it](http://www.wired.com/2012/07/spider-man-has-good-taste-in-textbooks/)!)

That book is definitely relevant for most of the stuff in BonusQ.pdf. However, it doesn't contain any material about PDEs.

Comment: I'll check this out because spiderman uses it =)

Answer (score 0):

You could try these books:
- An Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations by James C Robinson
- Differential Equations by Richard Bronson and Gabriel Costa

These are the books I used to use and they are pretty good, and your course, from your description, looks a lot like my first year differential equations course (I tried looking at your dropbox folder however for some reasons it couldn't load).

My lecturer's lecture notes are also very helpful, perhaps yours are too?

But yeah just a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah those files take a while to load for some reason, even though they're small. My lecturer's notes aren't helpful

Comment: Ah thats a shame, mine is very excellent that I don't actually need to read anywhere else. yeah i have just realized it took a while to load because a few minutes after I posted the answer it actually loaded